# SQL query using CASE

Tags: mysql

[image: Hi need query to get the email1Opened and email1Sent i.e yes/no for email_type 1 in a single row. Not on multiple rows.]

I am writing to a query to get the email1Opened and email1Sent i.e yes/no for email_type 1 in a single row. Not on multiple rows. So can you please help me out to print on single row.

```
select user_id, 
 business_id, 
 email_status,
 id, email_type,
 case when email_status='open' and email_type = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end email1Opened,
       case when email_status='Sent' and email_type = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end email1Sent
from email_track where business_id = 10;
```

Comment: You mean to say, columns instead of rows there?

Comment: Yes, single row for particular userId.

Comment: Can you type what your desired output is? Click edit on the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only email_type 1, you should use another where in your query:

```
select user_id, 
 business_id, 
 email_status,
 id, email_type,
 case when email_status='open' then 'YES' else 'NO' end as email1Opened,
 case when email_status='Sent' then 'YES' else 'NO' end as email1Sent
from email_track where business_id = 10 and email_type = 1;
```